# Show effictive ansible play

Tags: ansible

[**EDIT**]

Hi,

for my work I'm searching for a feature where I can at least see the paths that a play is using. The reason for is that I still need to describe in a seperate documentation what is happening... Kind of old fashion, but I have to.

We already found out, that `ansible-playbook --list-tasks` shows all tasks that will be executed. Though, the way to show an "effective" play is still missing.

I hope someone has an idea.

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 1):

There's `--list-tasks` option for `ansible-playbook`:

```
--list-tasks          list all tasks that would be executed
```

but it won't do any variable processing for you.

Comment: Sadly, that's only half of what I want. But thank you for the hint.